# Symfony2 multiple forms in one template

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

My app consists of Zones that can have many Devices.

When viewing a Zone, it needs to display a control for each Device in the Zone.

Each Device is completely independent, so embedding the Device forms in a Zone form seems unnecessary - I only want to deal with changes to one device at a time.

Currently I'm creating a form for each device and passing them to the Zone view template:

```php
public function viewAction($zone_id)
{
    $zone = $this->getZoneById($zone_id);
    $forms = array();

    foreach ($zone->getDevices() as $device) {
        $forms[] = $this->createForm(new DeviceType(), $device)->createView();
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Zones:view.html.twig', array('zone' => $zone, 'deviceForms' => $forms));
}
```

And then in the view template, I'm looping through the forms:

```php
{% for form in deviceForms %}
    {% include 'AcmeBundle:Devices:control.html.twig'
        with {'zone':zone, 'form':form}
    %}
{% endfor %}
```

This seems to be working ok, but I really need to change the template that renders based on the 'type' of Device. What's the cleanest way to do this? I can do something like:

```php
{% if form.vars.data.type == 'foo' %}
    {% include 'AcmeBundle:Devices:control-foo.html.twig'
        with {'zone':zone, 'form':form}
    %}
{% elseif form.vars.data.type == 'bar' %}
    {% include 'AcmeBundle:Devices:control-bar.html.twig'
        with {'zone':zone, 'form':form}
    %}
{% endif %}
```

but this seems like putting too much logic in the template? It would be better to assign the template to render to the form object somehow, but I've no idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add an option 'template' or whatever in the FormType via the controller,
In the FormType you must declare the default option 'template' and pass it the the form view.

```php
public function viewAction($zone_id)
{
    $zone = $this->getZoneById($zone_id);
    $forms = array();
    //You define a config for each type of device (you should use parameters)
    $templates = array(
        'foo' => 'AcmeBundle:Devices:control-foo.html.twig',
        'bar' => 'AcmeBundle:Devices:control-bar.html.twig',
    );
    foreach ($zone->getDevices() as $device) {
            //define your template here.
            $type = $device->getType();
            //add a template option in the form.
            $options['template'] == $templates[$type];
            $forms[] = $this->createForm(new DeviceType(), $device, $options)->createView();
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Zones:view.html.twig', array('zone' => $zone, 'deviceForms' => $forms));
}
```

Now in the DeviceType you should set the defaults options in the form, they will be merged with options we create in the controller.

```php
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {

    return array(
        //...other options...

        //this is the default template of this form
        'template' => 'AcmeBundle:Devices:control.html.twig'
    );
}
```

Then set the attribute on the form in the Builder

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->setAttribute('template', $options['template']);
    //...your fields here...
}
```

And finally, set the var template in the view.

```php
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
{   
    $view->set('template', $form->getAttribute('template'));
}
```

Now you can read the "template" option in twig, and include the corresponding template

```php
{% for form in deviceForms %}
    {% include form.get('template') with {'zone':zone, 'form':form} %}
{% endfor %}
```

Do not forget to add lines at the beginning of the FormType

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
```